# JS Filter is not filtering out element from array of objects based on !== conditional

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter, use-effect

Not sure what I am doing wrong here - it could be to do with how I am using `useEffect()` but I'm not clear on how to fix it. Essentially, I am running `.filter` over an array of objects and trying to make a filtered array that DOES NOT include a specific element from the array. I am quite new to using React and `useEffect()` in particular so think the trouble might come from there?

Here is the data:

```
[
{
author: 2
blurb: lorem ipsum
book_id: 2
cover_image: x
genre: "Literary Fiction"
id: 2
pub_year: 2020
title: "Shuggie Bain"
},

{
author: 2
blurb:  lorem ipsum
book_id: 14
cover_image: x
genre: "Literary Fiction"
id: 14
pub_year: 2022
title: "Young Mungo"
}
]
```

Here is the code:

```
export default function BookPage() {
  let { bookId } = useParams()
  const [bookInfo, setbookInfo] = useState({})
  const [booksByAuthor, setBooksByAuthor] = useState([{}])

  useEffect(() => {
    api
      .getBookById(bookId)
      .then((bookInfo) => {
        setbookInfo(bookInfo)
        api.getBooksByAuthor(bookInfo.author_id).then((books) => { //data above
          setBooksByAuthor(books)
          return null
        })
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }, [bookId])

  const otherBooks = booksByAuthor.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.book_id !== bookId
  })

[...]
```

This returns the same array as above, so isn't filtering out the value that matches the condition.

Comment: Can you please add the bookId in description and try printing bookId above the filter statement

Answer (score 0):

this usually happens because the useState takes milliseconds to update, it is better to perform the filter in the same function and then give the final value to the state

```
      api
      .getBookById(bookId)
      .then((data) => {
        setbookInfo(data)
        api.getBooksByAuthor(data.author_id).then((books) => { //data above
          const newArray = books.filter(obj => obj.book_id !== bookId);
          setBooksByAuthor(newArray)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

Also note that your "bookInfo" variable is repeated, this is not recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe book id is a string and obj.book_id is a number?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).